# Hide or Show Stateful child class when the parent class's radio buttons is clicked

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have two stateful classes which have their own radio buttons. The parent stateful class radio button should trigger the child stateful classes visibility to show or hide.

I am trying to trigger the child stateful class to be visible or hidden when i click one of the radio buttons in the parent class. But the child stateful class's build function does not get triggered even if i trigger it using setState().
I have tried to perform this using widgets in a single stateful class but i was not able to hide or show the child widget because the build won't re-run.

The RadioWidget Stateful Widget (parent) -

```
class RadioWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  final IncidentComponent data;
  RadioWidget(this.data);
  @override
  _CustomWidgetState createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<RadioWidget>{
  int _radioValue1 = -1;
  bool _visible = false;
  String textFontFamily;

  void _handleRadioValueChange1(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue1 = value;
      switch (_radioValue1) {
        case 0:
          setState(() {
            _visible = true;
            RadioDependentWidget(widget.data, false);
          });
          break;
      }
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(children: <Widget>[
     ListView.builder(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     shrinkWrap: true,
     itemCount: widget.data.options.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return Row(
       children: <Widget>[
       Radio(
       value: 0 + index,
       groupValue: _radioValue1,
       onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,),

       Text(widget.data.options[index].dataText,
       style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blueDarkColor,
       fontSize: 16.0,fontFamily: 'Euclid-Medium'),
       )
       ],
      );
    }),
  ],
 );
}
```

The RadioDependentWidget Stateful Widget (child) -

```
class RadioDependentWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  final IncidentComponent data;
  final bool _visible;
  RadioDependentWidget(this.data, this._visible);
  @override
  _CustomWidgetState createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<RadioDependentWidget>{
  int _radioValue2 = -1;

  void _handleRadioValueChange2(int value) {

    setState(() {
      _radioValue2 = value;
      print('index value is 22222 -> ' + _radioValue2.toString());
      switch (_radioValue2) {
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          break;
      }
    });
  }

@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
         ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: widget.data.options.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return Row(
           children: <Widget>[
           Radio(
           value: 0 + index,
           groupValue: _radioValue2,
           onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange2,),

           Text(widget.data.options[index].dataText,
           style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blueDarkColor,
           fontSize: 16.0,fontFamily: 'Euclid-Medium'),
           )
           ],
          );
        }),
      ],
     );
    }
```

I want to make the child stateful class load again when the visibility state has been changed from the parent stateful class.

**UPDATED**
The both stateful widgets are created in the main class -

```
 if (snapshot.data[index].dependencyId == '0'){
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RadioWidget(snapshot.data[index]),
                                  buttonsWidget
                                ],
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RadioDependentWidget(snapshot.data[index],
                                  true),
                                  buttonsWidget
                                ],
                              );
                            }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you need the child widget to appear?

Comment: I want the child widget to appear below the parent. I already have them in a column widget.

Comment: I don't think you have them in a column widget? `RadioDependentWidget` is only supposed to be created, to be put _nowhere_, when radio button value changes. At any rate what you have above is hardly [mcve]. Please provide it to have better help sooner.

Comment: I create both the widgets in the main class -
if (condition){
                              return 
                                  RadioWidget(snapshot.data[index])
                            } else {
                              return Column(
                                  RadioDependentWidget(snapshot.data[index],
                                  true),
                                ],
                              );
                            }

Comment: Then you should call `setState` on that _main_ class.

Comment: The whole point is that we have two widgets with radio buttons and how do i show or hide the other widget by interacting with the radio button.

Comment: What I'm saying is not necessarily against that; pass a function to be called to `RadioWidget`, in which you call `setState` and change the main class' variable that `RadioDependentWidget` depends on.

Comment: The problem is that the main function cannot be build again as there are values saved by the user and the saved value will be wiped off if we build the main class again. Thats why i only want to interact with the radio widgets to keep them visible or invisible in the UI.

Comment: Resolved the issue by referring - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider